# Invalid identifier in sql create table query

Tags: python, sql, cx-oracle

I understand from online articles that this issue is related to case-sensitivity with oracle sql. However, I cannot see the error in my query: For example:

```
ENGINE =  create_engine('credentials', pool_pre_ping = True) 
connection = ENGINE.raw_connection()
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE US (NAME VARCHAR2(255), ACTION_NAME VARCHAR2(255), CONNECTORNAME VARCHAR2(255), TRIGGER VARCHAR2(255), UPDATEDBY DATE, IDSET VARCHAR2(255), CONNECTORID VARCHAR2(255))")
```

Will give the error:

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Comment: `trigger` is a reserved word

Comment: @Mat that solves it! I was looking for a reserved word and thought it was `id` and had that changed to `idset`. I guess next time this error appears I should recognise that more than one exists.